# On identifiability: Why can't you include all levels of the two factors in a linear regression?

Tags: regression, identifiability

In Gelman and Hill, there is a passage on identifiability and it says:

"For example, you could not include both of the sex categories and all four of the age categories. It is simpler just to keep the constant term and all but one of each set of indicators."

Why so? 
For example,  if there are two factors such as sex(two levels) and ages(4 levels), why does having 6 predictors(m + f + a1 + a2 + a3 + a4) without a constant term make your model non-identifiable?

The reason why I feel stuck is I cannot think of an instance where two parameterizations are observationally equivalent.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider your dummy (indicator) variables, $m, f, a_1, a_2, a_3, a_4$;
specifically,
compute $m+f$ and $a_1+a_2+a_3+a_4$ for all observations.

What do you notice?

As a result, the linear combination $m+f - (a_1+a_2+a_3+a_4)$ is not estimable; the $X$ matrix is not of full rank.